# Triggering an Api.ai event through a external server

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es

It is needed to send an alert to the chat after a timer has started.

Scenario:

- *Remind me to call Bob in 5 minutes*
- *OK, will remind you in 5 minutes*

After this dialog fulfillment server will start a timer and when the time goes off, event is to be triggered.

But when using the event api in API.ai will not trigger a message to the chat window which was built using the JS api.

Is there a another way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This is very much possible. In the intents that you setup on API.ai, use @sys.time so that 'call me in 5 minutes' will return a time like 14:05:00. You can use this parameter to start a timer on your JS script and send the message when timer expires.

Comment: Usually the events are triggered from user side not from server side right ? and if I am using API.ai demo link to host my chat window, how is this possible ?

Comment: Yes, the client triggers the event - 'call me in five minutes' and then API.ai returns a time - 16:42:16 as the parameter if you've set that up. Then you'd need some kind of an external logic that interprets that time and converts it into a date object and then have code that'll trigger it at the right time. I don't think asynchronous time-related functions can run without some kind of server logic, so in your case, it won't work. If you're looking for a simple solution, check out Node-RED.